# Show that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f,g: I \mapsto \mathbb{R}$  defined on an interval such that $0 \in I$. Suppose that $(f.g):I\mapsto \mathbb{R}$  and  $ \frac{f}{g}: I\mapsto \mathbb{R} $ are differentiable at $x=0$ with $g(0)\neq0$. Show that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$

I'm trying to use this:

so that $f:X \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ be differentiable in $a\in X\cap X'$ it's necessary and sufficient that there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$a+h \in X \mapsto f(a+h)=f(a)+ch+r(h)$$ with $$\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{r(h)}{h}}=0$$ on the affirmative case we have that $$c=f'(a)$$
 let
 $j=f.g $ and $i=\frac{f}{g}$

$$j(a+h) = j(a) + ch + r(h)\\j(a+h)=f(a)g(a)+ch+r(h) \\ f(a+h)g(a+h)=f(a)g(a)+ ch +r(h)$$ and for $i$
$$ i(a+h')=i(a)+c'h'+r(h') \\ \frac{f(a+h')}{g(a+h')}= \frac{f(a)}{g(a)} + c'h' + r(h') $$

but it does not seem to be going anywhere, any help or tip would be great

thanks in advance

Comment: theres another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $c$ and $r(h)$ depend on the function! You're not allowed to use the same for different functions. For instance, $c=f'(a)$, so you cannot expect the same number is good for $g$.

I'd go more simply with
$$
\frac{\dfrac{1}{g(a+h)}-\dfrac{1}{g(a)}}{h}=
\frac{g(a)-g(a+h)}{hg(a)g(a+h)}=-\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}\frac{1}{g(a)g(a+h)}
$$
so that
$$
g'(a)=-\frac{g'(a)}{g(a)^2}
$$
This proves that $G(x)=1/g(x)$ is differentiable at $a$. Use the product rule for $f$ and $G$.

Going with the Taylor expansion as you're trying to do is trickier. Basically, given $g(a+h)=g(a)+ph+s(h)$, you want to find $G(a+h)=G(a)+qh+t(h)$. Since you want that $g(a+h)G(a+h)=1$, you need
$$
(g(a)+ph+s(h))(G(a)+qh+t(h))=1
$$
Note that $g(a)G(a)=1$, so the equality becomes
$$
g(a)qh+g(a)t(h)+G(a)ph+pqh^2+pht(h)+G(a)s(h)+qhs(h)+s(h)t(h)=0
$$
Dividing by $h$ and letting $h\to0$,
$$
g(a)q+\frac{1}{g(a)}p=0
$$
that is,
$$
q=-\frac{p}{g(a)^2}
$$
Now you can work out what $t(h)$ is.

Comment: thanks for the correction at the beggining, i will look and try to do the remaining steps. tks for the rest as well

Comment: why would i want g(a+h)G(a+h)=1 ?